# Is there an acceptable corresponding negative to "well off"?

Tags: negation, intensifying-adverbs

When we wish to refer to people who are living an affluent lifestyle or simply enjoying favorable circumstances in any particular area, we often say they are *well off*.

So far so good.

But listening to a podcast this afternoon, I heard the host try to express the opposite condition, and the term he used ("badly off") clanged in my ear. It just doesn't sound right.

Still, if we look at the positive expression "well off" we might judge that *well* functions as an adverb and *off* as an adjective. So if you want to introduce the negative condition, the corresponding adverb is *badly* (or *poorly*, etc.). But it still sounds awful.

Funnily enough, my ear's inner alarm remains silent when I hear someone say *bad off*, as in "They were pretty bad off in those days." So is that the answer? If so, why doesn't it yield to my immediate grammatical analysis? Why should *bad off* sound acceptable in that context but not *poor off* or some other combination of adjective/adjective? And it's not as if I'm trying to force-fit the corresponding negative construction: those already exist, and are heard all the time. What gives?

Note that I mean this question in the very narrow scope described above. I am **not** looking for synonyms of the negative. I don't want *destitute* or *unfortunate* or any of the others, and I will scowl at those who attempt to run me through with a thesaurus.

**Well, well**

I like J.R.'s contention that the word *well* is problematic in and of itself. Still, I'm not sure the other part of the team, *off*, should get off scot free. It has been overloaded in meaning for centuries. It can mean *apart from*, *in a state of disuse*, *rusty* ["His game was off due to a hangover"], *not operational at this time* ["The oven was off"], *inaccurate* ["The figures are off"], *extending from*, *abstaining from* ["He's been off alcohol for years"], and so on. Which is why when I hear "badly off" it makes me feel that *off* is being emphasized when it is not meant to carry the semantic freight with respect to positive or negative values.

**Off with their heads!**

Additionally, and with respect to the latter point, I see in the comments that some of you are trotting out Google word and book searches, which may or may not apply here. (Full disclosure: I have [mixed feelings about the use of such sources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu).) So it is worth pointing out that, taken out of context, the terms "bad off" and "badly off" do not always refer to the purported opposite of "well off":

> *He aimed for the target, but was badly off the mark.*
>
> *They were badly off in their estimate of how much time the project would take.*
>
> *Her performance was bad off the get-go.*

That last is colloquial, and may be straining the issue, but even if the search fails on account of the ambiguity of one term, it nevertheless fails for both.

Comment: It may be relevant to note that OED first records *well off* as "favourably circumstanced, fortunately situated" in 1733, with no examples suggesting any particular link to *financial* circumstances. Their first citation for the specific "well-to-do" sense is over a century later (1843). And here we are another century and a half later (some of us quite accustomed to hearing of people who are [*well hard*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=well%20hard)). It's hardly surprising if our "inner grammarians" don't always find consistency across the various usages occurring over time.

Comment: ...it sounds a bit "dated" to me, but it's not as if [*badly off*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22badly+off+then%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) hasn't been used as the opposite of *well off, well-to-do*.

Comment: Well on just doesn't work.

Comment: What usage of *well off* do you exactly mean? wealthy, fortunate, etc.

Comment: @Dodgie - I believe that's addressed in the opening line of the question: _living an affluent lifestyle or simply enjoying favorable circumstances in any particular area_.

Comment: Funny you mention your inner alarm being silent on _bad off_, but noisying up for _badly off_. For me, it's the exact opposite: I have no problem with_badly off_, which is a perfectly common phrase to me, one I would use myself with no hesitation; but _bad off_ turns the back of my head into a veritable cacophony of alarms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "bad off" outperforms "badly off" in Google search incidence by 641,000 to 441,000.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - Insofar as Google searches go, that's pretty much a dead heat. It may also be worth noting that [Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20well%20off,badly%20off,ill%20off,bad%20off,poorly%20off&year_start=1985&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3) has it the other way around.

Comment: Being a non-native, I am surprised that nobody mentioned *unwell*. Perhaps it might be because I am a non-native, the first word that came up to my mind when I read "negative to 'well off' was "unwell off". But I have not a slightest idea how it will sound like to the native ears.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: *Unwell* means *sick* or *ill*. It is the opposite of *well*, not *well off*.

Comment: @hildred *Well on* makes me think of old age or time, not affluence.

Comment: @SpareOom I had forgotten about that usage.

Comment: Can I ask exactly what further analysis/discussion you're looking for, Robusto?

Comment: @Ledda: I want someone to shed some light on what the grammatical aspects of the phrase are really, and whether they matter in this context. Should the parts be construed as adverb/adjective, with a corresponding negative polarity? If not, what?

Comment: I would propose "hard up".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think part of the issue is the way you have parsed *well off*. Consider, for instance, that the Free Dictionary defines [well-off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well-off) as a hyphenated adjective, and speculates that it derives from "to come well off" where *off* in this case indicates "circumstanced" with the overall meaning then being *to emerge from [sth] in good circumstances*.

If we start with that phrase — *to emerge from [sth] in good circumstances* — and work backward, we'd have *to emerge from [sth] in bad circumstances*. From this, we can jump to *bad off*, but I think we should look more closely at the other phrase that was mentioned, namely "to come well off."

It's an odd phrase, but I found it in use in Google Books, so I tried the most obvious opposite "to come poorly off". Sure enough, that's in use, or at least it was in literary use in the 1800s. That suggests strongly to me that the most appropriate negation of 'well-off' is actually 'poorly-off'.

However, the phrase "to come badly off" is also in regular literary use in the 1800s, so 'badly-off' could be perfectly cromulent as well.

Suffice to say, depending on how you look at it, any of *bad off*, *badly off* or *poorly off* could suit.

Answer (score 7):

*Badly off* may sound inelegant compared to *well-off*, simply because we are becoming accustomed to hearing, saying and even writing;  *wrong*, *bad* and *good* as adverbs.

<sup>All of the examples below are taken from *Macmillan Dictionary*.</sup>

1. Someone had tied the rope on wrong.
2. It hurts real bad when I run.
3. He's doing pretty good at his new job.

I also think it is the auxiliary, be, in "*they are* badly off" which might be to blame for the clanging noise in your head. I'll try my best to explain what I mean.

> *I am badly off*, to my ears doesn't sound bad.

In that last sentence *bad* is an adjective and the verb, *sound*, is a linking verb.

When *bad* is used in conjunction with other linking verbs, the resulting sentences appear normal and correct, so we have no problem with saying; *that looks bad*; *it smells bad*; *it sounds bad*; or *it tastes bad*. Similarly we don't have a problem with saying ***"I am well"*** to describe how we are feeling but when we use the adverb, *badly* in its place we have, ***"I am badly"***. Alarm bells, sirens and foghorns  should be blasting in our ears now.  Obviously, *badly* isn't the antonym of *well*, in this context any of the following would be more appropriate: *poorly*; *ill*; or *not well*.

As a result, "bad off" may sound more acceptable in conjunction with the auxiliary *be*, "They are bad off" sounds better because you/we/Americans are used to hearing the shorter phrase "They are bad"; *badly*, just doesn't work in the same way. I also suspect that when we wish to describe a family or a person that is not well off, we'll tend to say, *poor*, without thinking twice. If however, that word feels too harsh and/or it might be deemed as offensive, then a euphemism will be used; *not well-off*; *badly off*; *not rolling in money* etc.

Macmillan Dictionary defines the expression, *badly off*, [*someone who is badly off does not have much money*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/badly-off)

> They were worse off now than when they started the business.

I think *Macmillan* has come up with an acceptable corresponding negative to "well off" with *worse off*. It's not a perfect antonym, but your threat of scowling has *put me off* looking in a thesaurus. :)

Edit: I checked in The Chambers Dictionary 12th Edition, and the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary (1995) and neither one listed *bad off*, both have *badly off*. The first states: *adj poorly provided esp with money.* While the OALD says: *having little money; poor: "She's been very badly off since losing her job."*

Comment: Thanks. I think your note about the comparative form (*worse off*) does point in an interesting direction. +1

Comment: The OED has a late 19th century citation that opposes the *well-off* with the ***ill-off***, suggesting that since *well* and *ill* were considered opposites, this might not have been seen the way we see it now.  Saying that a family that was once a *well-off* one is now considerably *worse off* if not downright *ill off* might possibly fly in the right speaker or writer, but it might be hard to pull off in a more general case.

Answer (score 4):

> When we wish to refer to people who are living an affluent lifestyle
>   or simply enjoying favorable circumstances in any particular area, we
>   often say they are well off.

If we wish to refer to people who are living the *opposite* of an affluent lifestyle, we say they are *poor*.

If we wish to refer to people who are *not* enjoying favorable circumstances in any particular area, we say they are doing *poorly*.

For many senses of the word *well*, *poorly* is listed as [an antonym](http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/well).

If your podcaster wanted to express the opposite of *well-off*, it wouldn't have offended my ear to hear him use *poorly off* -- or, simply *poor*.

Comment: And forgive my lunge with the thesaurus, but the term that comes to mind as the opposite of _well-off_ is _down-and-out_.

Comment: This seems like obviously the correct answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem rests in how the word *well* doesn't always have a fitting antonym.

Let's say I go to work on Monday, and a coworker politely asks, “How are you doing?”

I could respond “I am good,” although some pedants might overhear that comment. Knowing that I frequent ELU, they might use that as a beachhead to attack what they perceive as shoddy grammar skills. Even though I'm convinced I would triumph, I'd rather not get dragged into that age-old debate, so I respond, “I am well, thank you.”

The same dialog happens on Tuesday and Wednesday. However, on Thursday, I'm feeling a bit suboptimal – not so under-the-weather that I could justify a sick day, but I would be a liar if I told my affable coworker that I was well. So, as soon as the friendly question is asked, I start searching my mind for a suitable antonym. “I am...” *What am I? I am not exactly ‘well,’ but what's a good word for what I am?*

As the day goes on, I mull over this opposite-of-well problem some more, and I notice there are many times when *poorly* works as a suitable antonym for *well*, and other times when *ill* does the job. Yet in some situations I feel stumped, and concede that I'm better off using *not*. For example:

- Dan looks like a slob standing next to Martha, who is, as always, well-dressed and well-groomed. On the other hand, Dan is *poorly dressed* and *not well-groomed*.
- Kevin – always the nice guy – is gaining some notoriety thanks to his new patent. Kevin, therefore, is *well-mannered* and *well-known* in the company.  But the new guy, Chuck, who sits in the next cubicle over, strikes me as a real jerk. He is *ill-mannered* and *unknown* – although that anonymity could soon be replaced by a bad reputation if he doesn't watch his step.
- Vera just got a new raise. Seeing her pleasant, confident smile as she climbs out of her brand new Lexus every morning, anyone can tell she's *well-adjusted* and *well off*. But Adam, the company janitor, is going through a rough spell. He just went through a rough divorce, and a good percentage of his meager wages are going to his ex-wife as child support, seeing that they had four kids together. He's, well, even though I think he's resilient, and that he'll do just fine in the long run, I'd just say he's *not so well-adjusted* at the moment, and *not too well-off*, either – although perhaps you'd prefer to use one of the [alternatives](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20well%20off,badly%20off,ill%20off,bad%20off,poorly%20off&year_start=1985&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Maybe I should invite Adam over for Chistmas; we've all been well-informed about how that can be a rough time of year for those who are struggling with both family and finances.

Comment: +1 for the analysis. Two things to ponder: Chuck will soon be well-known for being ill-mannered. And *well-adjusted* sounds to me like a personal judgment (not holding it together well) whereas the others are (at least ostensibly) factual descriptions. I'm not too happy about the description of Vera either; many well-off executives have a bright happy smile as they go about torturing flies or planning another reorganization (two very similar occupations).

Comment: @Tim - Fair enough. This is all fictional, of course, and I penned the scenario under the assumption that I knew the individuals well enough to differentiate between the real deal and the façade.

Comment: +1: I like this, but I still have some reservations. See my edit to the question.

Comment: As for _well_ being a problem in and of itself, we have the same problem with _good_. What would be the corresponding negative to _good-natured_? I would propose _ill-tempered_, not _bad-natured_.

Comment: @J.R.: But *bad-tempered* is commoner than *ill-tempered*, and you cannot be *well-tempered* unless you are a bar of metal (or a clavier).

Answer (score 2):

I once heard a story on NPR about entitled people who cut in line. A woman went to the head of a long line, offering no excuse except that she felt badly about doing so. "I'm sorry, I feel badly, but I must do this," she kept offering. She got away with it. The person telling the story was unsettled and pondered what *feeling badly* meant, and decided that the woman did, indeed, feel *badly*.

In her estimation (and I'm inclined to agree with her), "I feel badly" meant that *she had a deficiency in feeling*, that she didn't *do it well.* In truth, *if she did not have this deficiency*, she might have the same degree of empathy that stops us all from cutting in line. A normal person does not cut in line because it would make them *feel bad*.

This makes me pause whenever I'm inclined to say "badly" instead of "bad" simply because the former sounds more *proper*.

I've become a proponent of **bad happens**.

**Badly** has been **badly misused.**

There is not a hint of ambiguity if one hears that another is **bad off**. But there is no such complete lack of ambiguity when someone is *badly off*.

What (in this context) does **badly off** mean? It almost makes one wonder *where the responsibility lies.*

Is life justified in treating him *badly*? Did he do something *badly* which got him there? Was he, for instance, *bad* at his job? Or did he plan *badly*, and thus **badly miss his mark**? Or, does **bad** just **happen**?

*If bad happens*, no mental gymnastics are required. Plainly, he is just **bad off**.

Comment: I agree that *badly* has been misused, and that it isn't right for the negative here. But you haven't convinced me that the parallel you've set up is the best test. Still, +1 and welcome to ELU. If you can convince me I'll be happy to award you the bounty. Hey, it has to go to somebody, so it might as well be you.

Comment: ? *bad off* is clearly the antonym to **good off*. I wouldn't use either myself, but you may wish to; just not in opposition to *well off*.

Comment: @Tim, _bad_ can also be the antonym to _well_ (the adjective) in some cases: “How are you?” —— “I'm quite well” vs. “I'm quite bad”.

Answer (score 1):

An opposite to being (economically) "well off" is **struggling.** One may append the adverb "economically" for context, which would make it "struggling economically."

Comment: Thanks, but as I emphasize in the question itself, "I am not looking for synonyms of the negative. I don't want *destitute* or *unfortunate* or any of the others, and I will scowl at those who attempt to run me through with a thesaurus."

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many negative words for 'well-off'. For example: 'poor' and 'destitute'
[pasttenses antonyms](https://pasttenses.com/antonyms/well-off)

Comment: Read paragraph 6 of my question. And this comment is me scowling at you.